# Getting the width of a UIBarButtonSystemItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Is there a way to programmatically get the width of a UIBarButtonSystemItem.  The width property always returns 0 for system items. In particular, I want to get the exact width of the editButtonItem property of a UIViewController.

On the iPhone the value is 44 but it is a bit bigger on the iPad and I cannot nail it down.

Comment: Here are a couple possibilities, but it's my guess that any answer that works will probably rely on an undocumented API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066847/get-the-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem (note: I haven't tested any of this code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from the link that @JoBu1324 left of a comment.

Here is the code I used.

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = /*...*/;
UIView *view = [item valueForKey:@"view"]; 
CGFloat width = view? [view frame].size.width : (CGFloat)0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously *UIBarButtonItem* doesn't have the *frame* property. As *UIBarButtonItem* is a direct subclass of *NSObject*(which in turn don't have the *frame*), its impossible to get the frame of *UIBarButtonItem* from code(documented API's).

You have to rely on some other ways to find the width, as you found 44 is the width of *editButtonItem* in iPhone ;-)

Comment: it has to have some kind of frame whether or not it is called a frame; it's just not accessible via the public API

Answer (score 0):

The UIBarButtonItem has a property `width`, but it generally is 0 for system buttons. So, I usually use my custom button with my localized string inside the button, or use flexibleSpace UIBarbuttonItem to add a flexible space between left and right buttons. You can calculate the width of string by the method `-sizeWithFont` of NSString. A flexible space can be obtained by the style `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` of UIBarButtonItem.