# UIBarButtonItem position different when placed via storyboard vs. programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, uibarbuttonitem

In my app, I have a toolbar with `UIBarButtonItems`.
In most circumstances, the `UIBarButtonItems` are set via storyboard, and look as follows:

[image]

In a special case, I have to replace one `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically. This is done with the following code:

```
let rotatingButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
rotatingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "LocalizationInUseNoFix"), for: .normal)
rotatingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(localizationButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
rotatingButton.rotateStart()
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rotatingButton)
leftBarButtonItems![2] = barButtonItem
```

When the rotatingButton is displayed in the toolbar, it placed at a different position. It is shifted to the right, as you can see here:

[image]

How can I achieve to place both `UIBarButtonItems` at the same position?

**EDIT:**
By now I realized that the horizontal shift of the programmatically created `UIBarButtonItem` is not always the same, without any changes to the code: Sometimes it is shifted left, and not right:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I found a workaround:
If I set a width constrain to my button like

```
rotatingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

then the button is apparently always correctly placed. But I hate to hard-code constraints like this.
Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I found so far:

Get the width of a view of another bar button item using key value coding. This is from Jeremy W. Sherman’s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066847/get-the-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem).
Please note that it does not use any private API, see the discussion there. The worst thing that can happen is that the `view` property of the `UIBarButtonItem` cannot be accessed. In this case, I use a default value:

```
var leftBarButtonItems = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems

let rotatingButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
rotatingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "LocalizationInUseNoFix"), for: .normal)
rotatingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(localizationButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
rotatingButton.rotateStart()

// Get the width of the bar button items if possible, else set default
let leftmostBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItems![0]
let barButtonItemWidth: CGFloat
if let leftmostBarButtonItemView = leftmostBarButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {
  barButtonItemWidth = leftmostBarButtonItemView.frame.size.width
} else {
  barButtonItemWidth = 40.0
}
rotatingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: barButtonItemWidth).isActive = true
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rotatingButton)
leftBarButtonItems![2] = barButtonItem
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftBarButtonItems
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps to perform your task:

1. Store left bar button items into an `NSMutableArray`
2. Replace desired `UIBarbuttonItem`
3. Set leftbarbuttonitems to this new array

Hope this steps will work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but of course I did so - otherwise the new barButtonItem would not habe been shown in the toolbar!

Answer (score 0):

When you set the image on UIBarButton programmatically, the contentmode of the leftBarButtonItems becomes 'left' and rightBarButtonItems become 'right'. But from storyboard, it is centered. Set the image and adjust the contentMode as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure if I understood it right. What I tested is to set `rotatingButton.contentMode` in my code above to `.right`, `.left`and `.center`, but this had no effect to the placement of the button.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, It is not contentMode, it is "contentHorizontalAlignment" for UIButton & UIBarButton

Answer (score 0):

All are working fine for Navigationbar and Toolbar

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func leftAction(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func rightAction(_ sender: Any) {

}

@IBAction func changeLeftItems(_ sender: Any) {
    if let items = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems {
        var addItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        addItems.append(contentsOf: items)
        let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "3", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftAction(_:)))
        addItems.append(barItem)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = addItems
    }
    if let items = self.toolbar.items {
        var addItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        addItems.append(contentsOf: items)
        let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "L3", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftAction(_:)))
        addItems.insert(barItem, at: 2)
        self.toolbar.setItems(addItems, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code sets UIBarButtonItems into the toolbar, but it does not at all address my problem, how to replace a bur button item programmatically **in place**.

Comment: @IBAction func changeLeftItems(_ sender: Any) {
        if let items = self.toolbar.items {
            var addItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
            addItems.append(contentsOf: items)
            let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "L5", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftAction(_:)))
            addItems.remove(at: 1)
            addItems.insert(barItem, at: 1)
            self.toolbar.setItems(addItems, animated: true)
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
This is working fine for me. Best way is identify item to replace and change the content    

@IBAction func changeLeftItems(_ sender: Any) {
            if let items = self.toolbar.items {
                var addItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
                addItems.append(contentsOf: items)
                let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "L5", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftAction(_:)))
                addItems.remove(at: 1)
                addItems.insert(barItem, at: 1)
                self.toolbar.setItems(addItems, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I see it right, you replace a `UIBarButtonItem` by a new one. But my problem is different (see my question above): I have to replace a `UIBarButtonItem` by a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view, and this custom view is placed at another place than the replaced one.